# Efficient way to manipulate lists in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that starts like the following:

|  | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `Berlin` | `['Hamburg', 'Munich', 'Berlin', 'Stuttgart']` |
| 1 | `Tokyo` | `['Tokyo', 'Osaka', 'Kyoto', 'Sapporo']` |
| 2 | `Los Angeles` | `['New York', 'Chicago', 'Boston', 'Los Angeles']` |
| 3 | `London` | `['Birmingham', 'London', 'Glasgow', 'Liverpool']` |

I would like to delete cities that exists in Column1 from Column2 lists such a way that DataFrame becomes like this:

|  | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `Berlin` | `['Hamburg', 'Munich', 'Stuttgart']` |
| 1 | `Tokyo` | `['Osaka', 'Kyoto', 'Sapporo']` |
| 2 | `Los Angeles` | `['New York', 'Chicago', 'Boston']` |
| 3 | `London` | `['Birmingham', 'Glasgow', 'Liverpool']` |

Since looping row by row is against the dataframe logic, what is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `explode`, `query` and `gropuby`:

```
(df.explode('Column2')
   .query('Column1 != Column2')
   .groupby(level=0)
   .agg({'Column1': 'first',
         'Column2': list
       })
)
```

Or just straight `apply`:

```
df['Column2'] = df.apply(lambda row: [x for x in row['Column2'] if x!=x['Column1']], 
                         axis=1)
```